# standalone sdk manager in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Tools => Android => SDK Manager to open SDK manager, and then check the "Show Package Details" to see the the list of installed and not installed components.

I try to find "Sample" folder under individual Android version, but I just unable to find the "Sample" component. I am very upset because I want to install Gesture builder that is inside the "Sample" folder.

By accident, I click the "Launch Standalone SDK" to launch the screen that looks similar to the SDK manager on eclipse, and I find the Sample folder.

Anyone can tell me what the reason I am unable to find the Sample folder on opened SDK manager (there are 3 tabs: SDK Platforms, SDK Tools and SDK update Sites)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the samples for the particular sdk you're targeting. Furthermore, samples change from sdk to sdk.

So first find out which sdk, did the Gestures Builder sample come from, and then download that samples for that sdk.

After that, use the Android Studio wizard to create a project from the sample. Just be sure to target the same sdk (you can always change that target sdk later, once you have the sample).

Using Android Studio is best way to do it. There is no need to go to the folder itself and do things manually.

**Actually, GesturesBuilder seems to be very old, it's api level 4 (Android 1.6).** No wonder you have trouble finding it. My suggestion would be not to bother with it and try to find a more recent project example directly from github.com